# webdav files without all permissions go to lost+found

Tags: linux, liferay, webdav

I'm trying to connect the liferay 6.0.6 document library (installed in linux and running on tomcat) to an external mounted folder shared through webdav.

I'm using mount.dafvs to mount the folders in linux, but whenever I create or add via sftp a file to a mounted folder, it doesn't have the 777 permission as its folder and 95% of the times it simply goes to the lost+found folder, leaving there an empty file. So I can see files uploaded from the portal, but I can't upload files from my linux machine.

But if I change the permissions of the file to 777 and then I edit again or I upload it again from sftp replacing it, the file is there and can be seen/downloaded from the portal too!

any idea of why this is happening and how can I get this sharing works with R/W options from both sides?